# LocatorPane with transformed coordinates

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

In ["Introduction to Dynamic"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html), an example is given of a transformed slider, which goes to the left as the value increases. I am trying to do something similar with `LocatorPane`, but am having trouble extending methods of the example.

I am trying to create a modified `LocatorPane` control where I can move the locators in a transformed space. For the simplified case I show here I move locators about in the first quadrant, but I want to transform them dynamically to the third quadrant. This behavior should be bi-directional, so if I change my third quadrant dynamic values, I want the control display to update; this is where I have the trouble.

(I am aware that this particular example could be handled easily with the `ScalingFunctions` option in `ListPlot`, I can't use that approach in the more complex problem I am actually trying to solve.)

First, using the second argument to `Dynamic`

```
draw[locs_] := Graphics[{FontSize -> 18, FontWeight -> Bold, 
  (Text["*", #1] & ) /@ locs}]; 

flipper1[Dynamic[pts_]] := DynamicModule[{locs}, 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[locs, (pts = -#1; locs = #1) & ], 
  Dynamic[Show[draw[locs], PlotRange -> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True]], 
  Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All], Initialization :> {locs = -pts}]; 

pts = {}; 

flipper1[Dynamic[pts]]
```

This works fine while adding and moving locators, but when deleting locators the pts list is not updated, and when changing the `pts` list the `LocatorPane` does not update. For example, drop some locators and then evaluate `pts={}`; the locators do not go away.

`DynamicWrapper` solves the first problem:

```
flipper2[Dynamic[pts_]] := DynamicModule[{locs}, 
  DynamicWrapper[LocatorPane[Dynamic[locs], 
  Dynamic[Show[draw[locs], PlotRange -> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True]], 
  Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All], pts = -locs], 
  Initialization :> {locs = -pts}]; 

flipper2[Dynamic[pts]]
```

but I still can't get the bi-directional behavior I need. How can I can manipulate locators in a transformed space -and- change the values in the pts list and have the locators adjust accordingly?

**Update**
@halirutan 's solution inspired me, so he gets full credit for this. His solution works because he displays a second `LocatorPane` which is constantly executing the inverse transform. I wasn't intending to display a second pane, but we have `DynamicWrapper` for that:

```
flipper3[Dynamic[pts_]] := 
DynamicModule[{locs}, 
    DynamicWrapper[
        DynamicWrapper[
            LocatorPane[
                Dynamic[locs], 
                Dynamic[
                    Show[draw[locs], PlotRange -> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True]
                ], Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> All
            ], pts = -locs
        ], locs = -pts
    ], Initialization :> {locs = -pts}
];
```

So, the trick seems to be: wrap the `LocatorPane` in 2 layers of `DynamicWrapper`, one executing the transform and the other the inverse transform.

So, now bonus question: This seems awkward. This seems like just the type of situation the second argument to `Dynamic` was designed for. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it seems that using the second argument of `Dynamic` inside a `LocatorPane` doesn't recognize when locators are removed. That's unexpected, but not un-fixable since your `Graphics` is dynamic as well and und can make the assignment there.

If you want a bi-directional behaviour, you need both transformations i.e. from and to your transformed space. Furthermore, you need both ways of information flow: When `loc` is changed then `pts` needs to be changed and vice versa. Let us simplify this and use two global variables `pts1` and `pts2`, and the two transformation functions `f` and `finv`.

The core of the code is similar to what I had posted in my original answer. I thought you can work from there by yourself, but maybe it wasn't so obvious after all. Sorry for this. Here is a running example:

```
f[pt_] := RotationMatrix[Pi/4].pt;
finv[pt_] := RotationMatrix[-Pi/4].pt;

With[{lines = Table[{i, j}, {j, -1, 1, .25}, {i, -1, 1, .25}]},
 ClearAll[locator];
 SetAttributes[locator, {HoldAll}];
 locator[pts1_, pts2_, f_] :=
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts1],
   Dynamic[
    pts2 = f /@ pts1;
    Graphics[{Line[lines], Line[Transpose[lines]]},
     PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}},
     ImageSize -> 200
     ]
    ],
   LocatorAutoCreate -> All
   ]
 ]
```

The crucial part is that you need the symbols for your lists and not the values. You achieved this by using `Dynamic[pts]` which is perfectly fine and is used very often especially in GUI programming. I'm going to set an attribute to `locator` to provide the same behaviour.

Now, create the two dual locator panes:

```
pts1 = {};
pts2 = {};
Row[{locator[pts1, pts2, f], locator[pts2, pts1, finv]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this has the same problem. Manipulations in the flipper1 `Dynamic` are mirrored in the second `LocatorPane`, but manipulations of the locators in the second `LocatorPane` do not effect the locators in flipper1. (Would have been kicking myself if it were this simple, though)

Comment: @DanielW Sorry. Please see my rewritten answer.

Comment: Again, thank you. I studied your solution and realized it works because the second `LocatorPane` is displayed and executing the inverse function. But, if you never display the second `LocatorPane`, the inverse function is never executed. This gave me the inspiration for the `DynamicWrapper` solution I will post in my question.

Comment: @DanielW When I answer a question, it's not unusual that I might have misunderstood the key-point of the question. You are really welcome to join the [chat] every once in a while. Sometimes it's better when we can discuss things so that I get a better picture beyond the simplified example.